# redirect_to is not working into rescue block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, octokit

I am using Octokit so as to login.

```
helper_method :user

def show
end 

def user
  client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: session[:access_token])
  begin
    @user = client.user
  rescue => e
    redirect_to root_path
    return
  end
end
```

The root_path is in the config

```
  root to: 'home#new'
```

The rescue es executed, however the redirect_to isn't working, it return to the same view as the main method. Note: I read in many post that putting return fix it, nevertheless it didn't

Comment: Remove the ':' from root_path and make sure root_path is defined in your config/routes.rb file.  Also, 'return false' to halt further execution.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I misspelled. I updated the post. The root is defined and the root_path is defined properly

Answer (score 1):

Your code is calling the redirect_to method, but the rescue block is subsequently returning `nil`. Instead, combine the redirect and return into a single statement:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: session[:access_token])
begin
  @user = client.user
rescue => e
  redirect_to root_path and return
end
```

In fact you don't need the return at all, unless there is something after this statement in the method. This is because in Ruby the last statement is implicitly returned.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. The problem is that the code is into a helper method and not in the method controller?

Comment: I updated the post in order to clarify that @mysmallidea

Comment: Does Octokit really raise an exception if there is no user?

Comment: yes, it does. I figured out the problem. I was calling the method in a helper_method, so the method is called from the view and not from the controller

Comment: That would do it :) Maybe it makes more sense to set @user in a `before_action` - that way it would be available to the view and the controller, and you wouldn't have to keep calling on Octokit::Client.