# How to handle ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I've been searching how to handle error on Ruby and found this links but none of them works.

[redirect_to is not working into rescue block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981615/redirect-to-is-not-working-into-rescue-block)

https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/begin-rescue-not-working/118832/5

[Rails 3: Handle ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609531/rails-3-handle-activerecordrecordnotunique-exception)

https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-exception-vs-standarderror-whats-the-difference/

On my create method I have this

```
      def create
        @departments = Spree::Department.new(department_params)

        begin
          @departments.save
          flash[:success] = 'Department Created'
          redirect_to admin_departments_path
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
          flash[:notice] = 'Department name already exists'
          redirect_to admin_departments_path
          return
        end
      end
```

but the problem is it doesn't go to `rescue` block so it doesn't render the `flash[:notice]` it will render `flash[:success]` and redirect in short it will just do the `begin` even though it errors out.

Also on `@department.save` when I add the `!` (bang) if I input a name that is not unique I will get an error `Validation failed: Name has already been taken` which I wanted but it won't redirect instead it will go to error screen.

Is there something missing here?

Comment: try changing the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` to `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` and with the `save!`

Comment: @Subash not all heroes are in the air flying sometimes they're behind the keyboard coding! thank you champ! can you make this as an answer so I can Accept this?

Comment: btw how did you know that its `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`?

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` instead of `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` because thats the exception that gets raised by `save!` and `create!`.

I think I came across that, don't remember when, have a look [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html)

Comment: Thanks my guy. you saved me. 2hrs was wasted.